# Is it ok to run a "With tf.Session as sess:" inside training_data_generator while running fit_generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using tf.Session in tensorboard so I can't enable Eager mode.

I need to extract image patches in large image by using `tf.image.extract_image_patches`. So in my custom training generator, I add something like:

```
While True:
     num_patches = tf.image.extract_image_patches(input_big_pic, ksizes, strides, rates, patch_padding)
     With tf.Session as sess:
          inputs_after_tensor1 = sess.run(num_patches )
     .....some modifies for this ndarray "inputs_after_tensor1"....... 
     yield ({'input1': np.array(result_inputs_after_tensor1)})
```

My loss function is reducing but my output images on tensorflow are not changing so I wonder does the `tf.Session` in my training_data_generator affect the `fit_generator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and I think it's ok to run tf.session inside but it slows the training procedure.